# Simple matrix to matrix function using rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm trying to code a simple function in r using rcpp. I'm figuring out the syntax through http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html and used the sugar functions but could not get the following to work:

```
cppFunction('NumericMatrix fun(NumericMatrix x) {
    NumericMatrix dd = (exp(-(pow(x, 2)) / 2)*(3 - 6*pow(x, 2) + pow(x,4)))/sqrt(2*PI);
    return dd;
}')
```

Basically to apply a function in each element of a matrix. How can I make it to work?

Comment: This is covered by 3.5 in the [Rcpp faq](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, matrix multiplication is not yet supported for Rcpp `NumericMatrix`.  One option is to use [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) via [RcppArmadillo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppArmadillo).

```
# install.packages("RcppArmadillo")
Rcpp::cppFunction('arma::mat fun(const arma::mat& x) {
    arma::mat dd = (exp(-(pow(x, 2)) / 2)%(3 - 6*pow(x, 2) + pow(x,4)))/sqrt(2*PI);
    return dd;
}', depends = "RcppArmadillo")
```

Note `%` is the element-wise multiplication

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I however got an error using the code: ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [sourceCpp_3.so] Error 1

Comment: http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/rcpp-rcpparmadillo-and-os-x-mavericks-lgfortran-and-lquadmath-error/